# EasyWorship Copy/Paste/Update Foreign Character Error

Tags: unicode

I encountered this problem so far on EasyWorship, but I may have seen it before on other similar text editor applications. Recently, we updated our Windows software to Windows 10 and updated our EasyWorship program to version 6. Every single song that had foreign characters was swapped out with some Unicode equivalent like so:

> สิ่งที่ยับเยินเราจะสร้างใหม่
>   เมื่อไร้ทางไปเรามีเส้นทาง
>   แค่ไว้วางใจเราให้ความหวัง
>   เปิดใจอีกครั้งเราเฝ้ารออยู่

Will turn into

> ÊÔè§·ÕèÂÑºàÂÔ¹àÃÒ¨ÐÊÃéÒ§ãËÁè
>   àÁ×èÍäÃé·Ò§ä»àÃÒÁÕàÊé¹·Ò§
>   á¤èäÇéÇÒ§ã¨...àÃÒãËé¤ÇÒÁËÇÑ§
>   à»Ô´ã¨ÍÕ¡¤ÃÑé§...àÃÒà½éÒÃÍÍÂÙè

Does anyone know of a way to recover the original text? From first glance, it looks like characters are matched up specifically, e.g. ส = Ê (202), เ = à (224), ง = § (167), ห =  Ë (203), ก = ¡ (161), ค = ¤ (164), and many other similarities. The Unicode number order of transferred characters very closely aligns with the Thai alphabet, but when I go through the Thai Unicode numbers, and mod them doiwn 256 into the standard 0-255 Unicodes, they don't alighn.

Anyone know what to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to answer with the proper method, probably looking for the original files, or maybe EWS company has a way to recover the text, but I seriously just hardcoded a solution in Python. For the experienced, it should take about 20 to 40 minutes. Find characters in a certain range and swap them. It's simple!